# number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, array given

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel so sorry if this question seems simple and such.

I want to show the sum of the credit_memo in a given month and year but it shows the error: "number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, array given " and I don't know what is the source of the error.

CreditMemoModel

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreditMemoModel extends Model{
    public $table = "credit_memo";

    public function getTotalAmount(){
        return $this->credit_memo()->total_amount;
    }
}

?>
```

CMController (just the CreditMemo related ones)

```
use App\CreditMemoModel;
$credit_memos = CreditMemoModel::all();
$data               = [];
    foreach($date_arr as $date_index){
      foreach ($credit_memos as $credit_memo) {
            $data[$date_index]['credit_memos'][$credit_memo->total_amount] = 0;
        }
}
```

and the view

```
<td>Credit Memo</td>
        @foreach($date_arr as $date)
        <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($data[$date]['credit_memos'],2) }}</td>
        <?php $qtotal += $data[$date]['credit_memos']; ?>
      @endforeach
      <td class="text-right">{{number_format($qtotal, 2)}}</td>
```

Comment: print out the $qtotal variable, I'm sure it will be an array :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this line has some issue

```
<td class="text-right">{{ number_format($data[$date]['credit_memos'],2) }}</td>
```

in your view file it seems there are some issue with **$data** and **$date_arr** and **$date**

Could you please check this line..